# Creating fixed properties in InterfaceBuilder

Tags: macos, cocoa, interface-builder

I want to write a subview which is supposed to have a fixed height. The best would be, that I cannot change it in InterfaceBuilder, because it will be used a lot. If this would work out, it would be an awesome feature for me. But all custom views are freely resizable in InterfaceBuilder in Xcode. How can I achieve this? 
A good example is the NSLevelIndicator. Here the height property in the Size Inspector is disabled.

[image: Height is grayed out]

Is there a way to write my own views in such a way that a property is unchangeable? I did a lot of searching but was not lucky in finding something that matched my question.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
IBOutlet NSLevelIndicator   *LED;

NSRect rect = LED.frame;
rect.size.height = 10.0;
[LED setFrame:rect];
```